# Error deploying node.js app to elastic beanstalk: bundle.js not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I develop node.js app which are working perfectly in the local computer. But when I'm deploying it on AWS (elastic beanstalk) I get next error in the browser:

```
GET http://test.xxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/javascripts/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I deploy my app by aws interface:

First, I create a new app, then I create a environment with the following configuration:
- **Instances**
  Instance type:t2.micro
- **Software Configuration** 
  Proxy server: nginx, Node version: 6.10.0, Node command: npm start.

My application connects to an api to request information.

I need to know if I need to do anything else to make my app work